# Apply style for button group in Android

Tags: android, xml, button, styles

In my Android application I need to apply style for a group of buttons, instead of styling each button individual. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- put here style="@ststyle/Button_Style" -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="@string/b01" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="@string/b02" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button4" android:text="@string/b03" />
  <!--  end style  -->
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write the style for button like this ;

### style_btn.xml

```
<style name="style_btn" parent="Wrap">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_bg</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">90dp</item>
    </style>
```

### apply that style to your button :

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/attach_file"
                style="@style/style_btn"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/orange_bg"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/attach"
                android:text="@string/str_email_attach" />
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need the style to all of the **buttons** in your application, mention in your App theme style, Then no need to apply for every button.

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
</style>
```

If you need the style to particluar **button** , then apply to every button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    style="@style/Button"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late joining the party but I stumbled across this when trying to figure out the same problem myself.

What I did was:

Depending on how may button groups you have (say 3 for example) you need to subclass button and create three custom button classes (see below)

```
//Custom button 1
public class CustomButton1 extends Button {
    public CustomButton1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, R.attr.attrStyle1);
    }

    public CustomButton1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, null, R.attr.attrStyle1);
    }
}

//Custom button 2
public class CustomButton2 extends Button {
    public CustomButton2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, R.attr.attrStyle2);
    }

    public CustomButton2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, null, R.attr.attrStyle2);
    }
}

//Custom button 3
public class CustomButton3 extends Button {
    public CustomButton3(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, R.attr.attrStyle3);
    }

    public CustomButton3(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, null, R.attr.attrStyle3);
    }
}
```

You can see from the custom classes I have passed a custom attr.  These I define in my styles.xml and use them as reference.  See my styles.xml below:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="theme1">
    <item name="@attr/attrStyle1">@style/CustomButton1</item>
    <item name="@attr/attrStyle2">@style/CustomButton2</item>
    <item name="@attr/attrStyle3">@style/CustomButton3</item>    
   <item name="android:background">@color/warning_yellow_colour</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomButton1" parent = "@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_colour</item>
    <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/banner_background_sensor_colour</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomButton2" parent = "@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_colour</item>
    <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/button_red_colour</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomButton3" parent = "@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_colour</item>
    <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/text_blue_colour</item>
</style>

<attr name="attrStyle1" format="reference"/>
<attr name="attrStyle2" format="reference"/>
<attr name="attrStyle3" format="reference"/>
```

By linking the style to the attr, you then apply that style to your custom class, which you can then duplicate as many times as needed

```
 CustomButton1 theme1 = (CustomButton1)findViewById(R.id.theme1);
 CustomButton2 theme2 = (CustomButton2)findViewById(R.id.theme2);
 CustomButton3 theme3 = (CustomButton3)findViewById(R.id.theme3);
```

Hopefully this is of benefit to someone!